# linux create a file with the titles of the files inside a csv

Tags: linux, list, csv, output

So I have a file that has a list of file names, this file is a .csv

```
filename1

filename2

filename3...
```

and so on (there are hundreds of these)

What I want to do is output this list into their own files at the same spot as where this list is and make them into a .pdf file

so basically the folder will have

```
Filenamelist.csv

filename1.pdf

filename2.pdf

filename3.pdf
```

Any insight or help into this is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

here's my snippet of code

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [[-f "/mnt/c/users/jesse/desktop/test/list.csv"]] 
then 
while IFS='|' read -r pdfid 
do 
touch "/mnt/c/users/jesse/desktop/test/${pdfid}.pdf" 
done 
fi
```

I'm getting an error when I try to bash this

```
syntax error near unexpected token `fi
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

I'm using ubuntu on windows.

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with your code because you did not provide it or the errors you encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The error I am getting is ‘syntax error near unexpected token `fi'’ from this code ‘#!/bin/bash if [[-f "/mnt/c/users/jesse/desktop/test/list.csv"]] then while IFS='|' read -r pdfid do #touch "/mnt/c/users/jesse/desktop/test/${pdfid}.pdf" echo ${pdfid} done fi’

Comment: Please add your code and the result to your question.

Comment: will do, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `read` command in an iterative fashion, as described here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/

Comment: That would allow you to read the content needed to create the files. On each iteration, you'd just `touch` the file, interpolating the variable with the string `'.pdf'`

Comment: sorry I'm fairly new to stackoverflow, commenting is kinda weird. yeah that looks like exactly what I want it to do. Do i just copy and paste that command into the window or should I make a bash script?

Comment: Pasting it into an executable file would lend to easier debugging, but you can do either. Start by just outputting the lines, then outputting the lines concatenated with '.pdf' at the end. Finally, instead of echoing text to stdout, use `touch` to actually create the files.

Answer (score 0):

would this work?

```
if [[ -f "/mnt/c/users/jesse/desktop/test/list.csv"]]

then

while IFS='|' read -r pdfid

do

touch "/mnt/c/users/jesse/desktop/test/pdfid.pdf"

done < "/mnt/c/users/jesse/desktop/test/list.csv"

fi
```

Comment: You'll want to use interpolated string, so, turn the touch into this:
`touch "/mnt/c/users/jesse/desktop/test/${pdfid}.pdf"`.


As a general rule, as part of the development process, I'd start with `echo` instead of touch, to debug my script to make sure it works correctly.

Comment: thanks for the input! I am trying to bash this script `#!/bin/bash
if [[-f "/mnt/c/users/jesse/desktop/test/list.csv"]]
then
while IFS='|' read -r pdfid
do
#touch "/mnt/c/users/jesse/desktop/test/${pdfid}.pdf"
echo ${pdfid}
done
fi` and i'm getting a syntax error for line 9 (syntax error near unexpected token `fi') any ideas as to what's going on?